# Flash AS3 debug animation in browser (html)?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, browser, actionscript

Is there a way to debug a application in the browser (html)?

I have a small app that functions perfectly in flash and as a swf, but as soon as I get it in a html, online or off, it doesen't work. I know it is embebed properly because I tried changing the background color and it changes in the html as well, but aparently doesen't load.

It comunicates with a online text file, but I discarded any crossdomain problems, since they are on the same server (and it works in flash, as I mentioned earlier).

So, I'm really stumped. The main problem is that I don't even know the error, so I can't figure out what's wrong. Is there a way to do a "catch any error that comes up and show it in a text box"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox with flashfirebug plugin will show flash errors in the console.

It is also possible to debug a swf in a browser with [Flash Develop](http://flashdevelop.org) using remote debugging(Debug>Start Remote Session).